# Remove values that throw Unicode Encode Errors from pandas dataframe when writing to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a dataframe to a .csv file using `df.to_csv()`.

I get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It's a large dataframe, so it's not obvious what value threw the error.

Is there a way to remove characters that can't be encoded from the dataframe prior to write?

Comment: Can you not just pass the encoding as a param to `to_csv`? like `df.to_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: Thanks! This solves the error on write. When I read the `df` back into Python (`pd.read_csv()`), all numeric values have been converted to string.  Checking the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) now, but wondering if there's a way to avoid this ...